# select an item from a spinner and display it on a text view

Tags: java, android, user-interface

How can I select an item from a spinner and then display it on a text view without using a button, I know I have to use onItemSelected() but I don't know how.
here's my layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/selectSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_color">
</Spinner>
```

and my textview which is empty:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundColorTV"
    android:text="@string/background_color_TV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
backgroundColorTV.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
```

write this line into onItemSelected() method. Something like this

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    backgroundColorTV.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
}
```